# Calling web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call a web api and I want to see what response I get. WOuld it be 200, 204 or 500.

I am trying it fot thr first time.

```
public void foo()
{
  RunAsync(); // dont know what it return type will be
}


static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("pid=23&lang=en-us");

            }
        }
```

Here, the code stops on the last line. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  `StatusCode` property of your HttpResponseMessage.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("pid=23&lang=en-us");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    //was success
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();     
    //checck result string now
   //you can also deserialize the response to your custom type if needed.
}
else
{
  var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
  //do something with this
}
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee434093.aspx) is the official documentation of HttpStatusCode enumeration which gives you a complete list of possible status code values.

Since your method returns a Task, you should await it when you call it.

```
public async Task foo()
{    
   await RunAsync(); 
}
```

Comment: Here, I get reponse like found and not found. Can I get response like 500, 204 or 200 ??

Comment: When you call it, do like `await RunAsync`. Also you probably are missing a `?` before `pid=23`

Comment: Yea. You can read the response.StatusCode and compare it with list of available items in the link i posted in the answer.

Comment: If I do await RunAsync i need to keep async always, and it is called by many methods. Is there a way to just return a string message or something ?

Comment: If you want to execute your GetAsync in an non async method, use `var response = client.GetAsync("?pid=23&lang=en-us").Result;` Change your method from Task to void and remove async attribute